# single line input for list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am provided with a number:

example:  `12345`

I’m supposed to split each digits of this number and append it to a list **(list of integers)**.

```
num = list(int(input('Enter the number\n')))
print(num)
```

Get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError 'int' object is not iterable
```

Required output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Enter the number
12345
[12345] this is the output i'm getting but i need as [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Set of numbers? Like 12345 34567 2 3 or 1 2 3 4 5 or 12345 ?

Comment: Please don't spam tags, only use the tag for the actual python version you're requesting help with (I'm assuming python 3 based on your code)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, include the desired result -- you *did* supply the actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
num = list(map(lambda x: int(x), input('Enter the number\n')))
```

Comment: `lambda x: int(x)` is equal to `int`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
num = [int(i) for i in input("input your number")]
print(num)
```

Comment: Using iPad so it’s kind of difficult to put this in code blocks, please feel free to edit and put the solution in code block

Comment: @Tomerikoo ya just missed that it is used in typecasting  so both the expression are same

Comment: @Tomerikoo Done

Comment: I have fixed the quotes `"` as for some reason yours were weird. when I copied the code it was a syntax error

Comment: @Tomerikoo Cool. Actually was working on Ipad, and it's kind of messy to write code in a code block using it, so

Comment: @Jeevan my answer was before any other answer, Why answer acceptance removed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list comprehension to get the output [1,2,3,4,5]. It'll give you back a list as output.

The reason you are getting the error: TypeError 'int' object is not iterable
is because list() only takes objects that are iterable and an int is not iterable at all.

Here's some example code of the list comprehension that you can use:

```
returned_list = [int(x) for x in input("Enter your number: ")]
print(returned_list)
```